# Envío de información SQLite a un webservices

Tags: android-studio, webservice, android-sqlite

Tengo un problema tengo una aplicación que es online y offline el cual que si está en modo offline guarda información en una tabla de `SQLite` y cuando ya hay conexión debería de mandar la información guardada en la tabla a un web service pero me esta crasheando al momento de querer consultar la tabla y no se como solucionar el error y mandar la información 
este es el mensaje de error:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   OFFLINE_TABLE (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM OFFLINE_TABLE

Así es como guardo la información:

```
public boolean addRepartoOffline(String cartaPorte,String numPedido,String HoraLLC,String FechaLLC,
                                 String HoraInC,String FechaInC,String HoraFinC,String FechaFinC,
                                 String HoraSaC,String FechaSaC,String HoraLLD,String FechaLLD,
                                 String HoraInD,String FechaInD,String HoraFinD,String FechaFinD,
                                 String HoraSaD,String FechaSaD) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_CARTAPORTE_OFFLINE, cartaPorte);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_PEDIDO_OFFLINE,numPedido);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_HORA_LLEGADA_C,HoraLLC);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_FECHA_LLEGADA_C,FechaLLC);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_HORA_INICIO_C,HoraInC);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_FECHA_INICIO_C,FechaInC);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_HORA_FIN_C,HoraFinC);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_FECHA_FIN_C,FechaFinC);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_HORA_SALIDA_C,HoraSaC);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_FECHA_SALIDA_C,FechaSaC);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_HORA_LLEGADA_D,HoraLLD);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_FECHA_LLEGADA_D,FechaLLD);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_HORA_INICIO_D,HoraInD);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_FECHA_INICIO_D,FechaInD);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_HORA_FIN_D,HoraFinD);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_FECHA_FIN_D,FechaFinD);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_HORA_SALIDA_D,HoraSaD);
    contentValues.put(COLUMNA_FECHA_SALIDA_D,FechaSaD );
    Log.d(TAG, "addDataRepartosOffline: Adding " + cartaPorte+" "+numPedido+" "+HoraLLC+" "+FechaLLC+" "+
            HoraInC+" "+FechaInC+" "+HoraFinC+" "+FechaFinC+" "+HoraSaC+" "+FechaSaC+" "+HoraLLD+" "+
            FechaLLD+" "+HoraInD+" "+FechaInD+" "+HoraFinD+" "+FechaFinD+" "+HoraSaD+" "+FechaSaD+" "+" to " + TABLE_REPARTOSOFFLINE);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_REPARTOSOFFLINE, null, contentValues);
    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

y asi he tratado de consultar la tabla

```
            Cursor reconeccion = mDatabaseHelper.getRepartoOffline();
            if (reconeccion.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                  String NumReparto= reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("numPedido"));
                    String CartaPorte = reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("cartaporte"));
                    String LlegaHCliente =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("horaLlegadaCliente"));
                    String LlegaFCliente =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("fechaLlegadaCliente"));
                    String InicioHCliente =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("horaInicioCliente"));
                    String InicioFCliente =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("fechaInicioCliente"));
                    String FinHCliente =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("horaFinCliente"));
                    String FinFCliente =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("fechaFinCliente"));
                    String SalidaHCliente =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("horaSalidaCliente"));
                    String SalidaFCliente =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("fechaSalidaCliente"));
                    String LlegaHDescarga =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("horaLlegadaDescarga"));
                    String LlegaFDescarga =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("fechaLlegadaDescarga"));
                    String InicioHDescarga =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("horaInicioDescarga"));
                    String InicioFDescarga =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("fechaInicioDescarga"));
                    String FinHDescarga =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("horaFinDescarga"));
                    String FinFDescarga =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("fechaFinDescarga"));
                    String SalidaHDescarga =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("horaSalidaDescarga"));
                    String SalidaFDescarga =reconeccion.getString(reconeccion.getColumnIndex("fechaSalidaDescarga"));
                    String Descripcion =null;
                    String ClaveParada= null;
                    String TipoParada= null;
                    String cargaHora=null;
                    String cargaFecha=null;
                    String tvLatitud=null;
                    String tvLongitud=null;
                    numeroReparto = Integer.parseInt(NumReparto);
```

Asi lo tengo en mi DataBase Helper

```
  public Cursor getRepartoOffline(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "  + TABLE_REPARTOSOFFLINE;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: instalastes la app y luego agregastes columnas a la tabla?

Comment: Podrías mostrar la clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper`.?